# Spark 3.4.1, Jakarta Servlet 6.0.0 Compatibility Issue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, jakarta-migration

I am attempting to create a spark session in spring application.
Since spark uses jersey servlet.
On adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

it  gives error

```
Jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
```

but it is mentioned on maven repository that javax is moved to jakarta https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api . After explicitly adding javax servlet-api 4.0.1

It now gives other errors.

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:514) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:386) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:749) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.ServerInfo.addHandler(JettyUtils.scala:492) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$2(SparkUI.scala:76) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$2$adapted(SparkUI.scala:76) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$1(SparkUI.scala:76) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.$anonfun$attachAllHandler$1$adapted(SparkUI.scala:74) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.attachAllHandler(SparkUI.scala:74) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$27(SparkContext.scala:652) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$27$adapted(SparkContext.scala:652) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:652) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2740) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1026) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1020) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at 
   3 lines in between
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am using Spring Boot version is 3.0.6, Java 17, Spark 3.4.1 (spark-core, spark-sql) , Jakarta Servlet 6.0.0. These are my dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried changing spark to older version.
Not using jakarta servlet 6.0.0 and instead of spring boot 3.0.6 using 2.7.12 , it runs successfully. But since I am using spring boot 3, jakarta servlet 6.0.0 comes with it.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution because I ended up in the same situation. This is because Spark UI need a servlet at some point and therefore pulls its own version of servlet-api which is not compatible with springboot 3 one ...

Answer (score 0):

This issue happening while we run the spark in local mode.
We resolved by, created shaded spark-core jar with jakarta transformer

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>shade-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedClassifierName>jakarta</shadedClassifierName>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <dependencyReducedPomLocation>${project.build.directory}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
                <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
                    </rules>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: why does this issue not happen in cluster mode?